# Slick Slider, position object above slide absolute

Tags: overflow, css-position, slick.js

I've made a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sr0tnqL5/) explaining what I would like to do with slick slide:

```
<div class="slider">
  <div>
     <div class="absolute">
        Blabla
     </div>
     <img src="http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/img/fonz1.png" />
  </div>
  <div>
     <img src="http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/img/fonz2.png" />
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.absolute {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    position: absolute;
    top: -50px;
    background-color: #900;
}
```

In short: The red box in the first slide is invisible because it's inside the slide that has overflow hidden. I need the box to be a part of the first slide only and move with the slide.

Can anyone fix the JSFiddle example so this works, that would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I found a hack for this you have to set a margin-top or padding-top on each slide element.

```
.slick-slide{

    padding-top:25px 
    //margin-top:25px also working
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Working fine. Make sure red box should be position absolute & and each slider have position relative. so that your red box is belong to that slide only

```
.slider > div{
    position: relative;
}
.absolute {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    position: absolute;
    top: -50px;
    background-color: #900;
}
```

Comment: Hi :) Thanks for your reply - I added the position relative to the css in this fiddle: [link](https://jsfiddle.net/6v9q796n/) but the red box still dissappears underneath the top of the slider.

Can you please mod the fiddle to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

the red box in the first slide will always stay alone, because it has the position as 'absolute'.
but you could solve this.

- absolute: The element is removed from the normal document flow, and no space is created for the element in the page layout. The element is positioned ***relative to its closest positioned ancestor***

that's why we add to the parent div :

```
position: relative
```

now the code will look like this :

```
<div class="slider">
  <div style="position: relative">
     <div class="absolute">
        Blabla
     </div>
     <img ...>
  </div>
  <div>
     <img ...>
  </div>
</div>
```

and if you want you could play with the position of the parent  to see how is this working...

```
<div style="position: relative; left: 1">
```